# Poor Phd and future

Tags: phd, research-process

I had a poor phd work and my boss was also not interested which means I publish in low quality journals.  Can I do better research and join better labs after phd? How to do it?  I regret my phd period I lost,  can I now undo that period?

My research areas are molecular biology or life sciences.

Answer (score 2):

Whether you can do better research is up to you provided that you can find a better environment (and supervisor) with which to work. I assume that you need to be associated with a lab to do your work. The lab in which you did the PhD probably isn't the right place.

You need to find a lab in which to get hired for future work. In applying, try not to be quite so negative as you are here, but when asked, you can suggest that you got some bad advice and are working to get beyond that. Present yourself in the most positive way that you honestly can to a new employer.

In some ways, you may be a bit behind, but a PhD is still a PhD and hopefully you have learned the skills you need to contribute to a lab and to the scientific community.

But the past is the past and you can't undo it. You can only move forward. Put your efforts there.